# Sliding Menu Layout and Main layout collide

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am currently developing an android app with sliding menu, my code compiles but my sliding menu is colliding with my main layout like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/eALCZCK.jpg]

xml of main layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />


   </LinearLayout>
```

xml of menu layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >


  <ListView
 android:id="@android:id/list"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
 />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My main activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ListView txV;
    //Creating array for List View with dummy items
private final String[] menuItems ={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
    "sit", "amet",
    "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
    "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
    "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
    "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

private FB_Login mainFragment; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);


        // Sets and configures the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);// =7dp
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);//=150dp
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setShadowDrawable(R.color.Black);

        menu.setMenu(R.layout.layout_menu);

        //Sets listView for sliding menu
        txV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        txV.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuItems));


          if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            mainFragment = new FB_Login();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            mainFragment = (FB_Login)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }

    }
```

My facebook login works properly, the only problem is this. I played with offsets but didn't work out. I checked xmls but did not see any problem. Any advices for the rookie?

Thanks

Temporary Solution: Well changing this line "menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);" prevents the collision but still I want to know why it happened when I left that field as "SLIDING_CONTENT".

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative layout for your layout menu. Relative layout supports z index placement(one view above another). Due to this your facebook button is spanning two views. Also check this line

```
menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);// =7dp
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);//=150dp
```

The way your screenshot is behaving is suggesting that your sliding menu is configured from the right side of your screen.

```
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
```

On the contary your listview is from right. My guess is your main layout is behaving like sliding menu.